# Deleting specific DateTime column rows from a DataTable

Tags: c#, datetime, dataset, enumerable

I am currently selecting some specific rows from a datatable which contain DateTime column. The idea is to delete these specific rows after collecting them.

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DateTime?> dates =
    dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime?>(dateColumn))
    .Where((r => r < minDate || r > maxDate));
```

I am getting the rows in a RowCollection, how do i actually delete these rows from the Dataset/DataTable? Or perhaps a better way to do it.

Comment: Why not simply loop through the rows and invoke `table.Rows.Remove(..`?

Comment: Your statement _a datatable which contain DateTime column_ needs clarification. In which case your table doesn't contain a DateTime column?

Comment: What kind of clarification do you need? I got a datatable with some columns and the one i am dealing with is a datetime column. The table itself has a lot of rows, some rows needs to be deleted depending on the datetime value of a specific datetime column.

Comment: Instead of deleting the rows you don't want change where to keep rows you do want and put results in a new table  .Where((r => r > minDate && r < maxDate))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a row from a datatable you need to perform some operations.

First find all the rows that match your criteria

```
var rowsToDelete = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>(dateColumn) < minDate ||
                              r.Field<DateTime?>(dateColumn) > maxDate));
```

Now start marking each row as deleted.

```
foreach(DataRow row in rowsToDelete)
    row.Delete();
```

Notice that the previous step marks only the rows as deleted, the rows are still in the datatable but they are no more accessible (And trying to use a row with its RowState == DataRowState.Deleted causes an exception)

Now you could remove these rows from the DataTable calling

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

Also note that this code doesn't change anything on the database table but only makes changes to the *in memory* DataTable. If you want to remove the rows from the database table then you need specific ADO.NET code specific for your database - For example in Sql Server you need to call the SqlDataAdapter.Update method for a batch delete or a sequence of single SqlCommand with the appropriate DELETE statement for each of the row to delete.

Comment: Sweet, this worked flawless! Especially with the AcceptChanges().